# DataTables: Sorting table by columns, fixed i++ value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, datatables

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th class="nosort">#</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Location</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

I have table and I'm using DataTables so sort columns. I have a while loop that produces the following cells.

```
# |  Name  | Age| Location
----------------------------
1 | Donald | 37 | Sidney
2 | Janice | 54 | London
3 | Alice  | 44 | California
```

The # is incrementing i++ as it goes through the loop. The 'nosort' of DataTables works fine, I cannot click the #. However, when I click Name for example, I want to sort the columns by Name, the following happens.

```
# |  Name  | Age| Location
----------------------------
3 | Alice  | 44 | California
1 | Donald | 37 | Sidney
2 | Janice | 54 | London
```

As you can see, the # "changes" according to Name. I want the # column created with i++ to be fixed, only displaying the position so it won't change when I sort by name or age for example. How can I achieve this?

edit: my current code

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   "paging": false,
   "info": false,
   "bFilter":  false,
   "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
"columnDefs": [{ "targets": 'nosort' }]
});
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and the problems you've had?

Comment: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#aaSortingFixed may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [**`drawCallback`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to do this  :

```
..
drawCallback: function() {
  $('#example tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    tr.children[0].textContent = i+1;
  })
}
..
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hr8fy3vw/**

Since the content of the column is resetted all the time, there is no need for going through the API. Also, when iterating with jQuery over `<tr>`'s only *visible* rows will be processed - a timesaver compared to use the API's `every()` and `each()` methods.

Comment: thank you. It works on jsfiddle as intended but I have not managed to make it work with my own code unfortunately. That is my bad as I had zero experience with jQuery before finding out DataTables.

Comment: @DxDogo, do you get any errors in the console and so on ...?

Comment: finally I got it working and it works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

See [Index column](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html) article on how to add index column.

Use the code below and change `example` to your table ID.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omhw937s/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: thank you. How would I need to alter it if I want to get rid of the search and display all in one page instead of 10 per page? See my edited first post for current code.

Comment: @DxDogo, use `searching: false` to disable search and `paging: false` to disable paging.